# Input impedance of PIC32 ADC pin

Tags: pic, adc, filter, low-pass, input-impedance

I want to measure temperature of an oven using a thermocouple. The maximum change in the temperature will be 1<sup>o</sup>C/s. The amplifier section will already contain a low pass filter, but I want to put an extra passive RC filter very close to the ADC input pin of PIC32MX270F256B. However, I can't decide a suitable resistance value (R) because I can't find the input impedance of the ADC pin neither in the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/60001168F.pdf) nor in the [family reference manual](http://hades.mech.northwestern.edu/images/2/21/61132B_PIC32ReferenceManual.pdf). What range of resistance value can I use here?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiTgsk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Reference Manual seems pretty clear on the subject:

> The analog input model of the 10-bit A/D converter is shown in Figure
>   17-22. The total acquisition time for the A/D conversion is a function
>   of the internal amplifier settling time and the holding capacitor
>   charge time. For the A/D converter to meet its specified accuracy, the
>   charge holding capacitor (CHOLD) must be allowed to fully charge to
>   the voltage level on the analog input pin. The analog output source
>   impedance (RS), the interconnect impedance (RIC), and the internal
>   sampling switch (RSS) impedance combine to directly affect the time
>   required to charge the CHOLD. The combined impedance of the analog
>   sources must therefore be small enough to fully charge the holding
>   capacitor within the chosen sample time. After the analog input
>   channel is selected (changed), this acquisition function must be
>   completed prior to starting the conversion. The internal holding
>   capacitor will be in a discharged state prior to each sample
>   operation.

[image]

> An external RC filter is sometimes added for anti-aliasing of the
>   input signal. The R component should be selected to ensure that the
>   acquisition time requirements are satisfied. Any external components
>   connected (via high-impedance) to an analog input pin (capacitor,
>   Zener diode, etc.) should have very little leakage current at the pin.

The Datasheet gives a recommended input impedance for the ADC:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I found it in table 29-32 at page 275. Thank you.